# The format of output in R

Tags: r, format

Formatting data for output in R is hard which package I can use to have a  some functions to create good looking tables quickly for R?

Comment: Any reason you are using the `cat()` function rather than `write.table`?

Comment: If you insist on using `cat`, you'll have to set `options(width)` beforehand to prevent over-run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set the `fill`option to `true` or some `logical` value:

> a logical or (positive) numeric controlling how the output is broken
>   into successive lines. If FALSE (default), only newlines created
>   explicitly by " " are printed. Otherwise, the output is broken into
>   lines with print width equal to the option width if fill is TRUE, or
>   the value of fill if this is numeric. Non-positive fill values are
>   ignored, with a warning.

something like:

```
cat( out, file="mydata.txt", fill = 100, sep="\n", append=TRUE)
```

or simply you get your own code and make it `FALSE`, but the problem with your code is that you have omitted the comma after the `FALSE`, so basically this should work but check your comma in the code line.

```
cat( out, file="mydata.txt", fill = FALSE, sep="\n", append=TRUE)
```